# cat on a quoted variable fails

Tags: bash

I have this code snippet:

```
userjobs=$(grep -rw "$USER" /my/job/dir/|awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq|rev|cut -c 2-|rev)
for job in "${userjobs[@]}"; do
  cat "$job"
done
exit 0
```

When I run it as is, I get the following output:

```
cat: /my/job/dir/45
/my/job/dir/46: No such file or directory
```

However, if I unquote $job, I no longer receive this behavior, and it cats each of the files as expected.

I've done some reading up on globbingand splitting to see if this is occurring, but it seems like double-quoting should prevent that from happening. Can anyone explain why the behavior is different between `"$job"` and `$job`?

Comment: `"${userjobs[@]}"` only makes sense if `userjobs` were an array, but it's not; it's just a regular string.

Comment: ...btw, a pipeline with that many components is generally a code smell (which is to say, an indication that there's a better way to solve your larger problem).

Comment: In particular, piping `grep` to `awk` is rarely necessary, since `awk` can do its own matching. `sort | uniq` should be `sort -u`, but `awk` can also do its own uniquing.

Comment: assuming their sort has a -u.

Comment: `awk` could also remove your last two characters, making the double `rev` moot as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your variable looks like:

```
userjobs='/my/job/dir/45
/my/job/dir/46'
```

If you expand it as an array, with `"${userjobs[@]}"`, that it acts as an array with exactly one element -- that string. Thus, behavior is identical to:

```
userjobs=( [0]='/my/job/dir/45
/my/job/dir/46' )
```

...still exactly one string with a literal newline in it.

Thus, `cat "$job"` looks for a file with a literal newline in its name.

---

To load your result into a real array you can iterate over with `"${userjobs[@]}"` expanding to a distinct element per line, use:

```
readarray -t userjobs < <(grep ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`userjobs` needs to be an array. Put parentheses around the value when assigning it:

```
userjobs=($(grep -rw "$USER" /my/job/dir/|awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq|rev|cut -c 2-|rev))
```

Comment: NMDV, but [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). Better to suggest `readarray -t userjobs < <(...)` so globs aren't expanded, or *at least* set `IFS=$'\n'` first so non-newline whitespace isn't split into extra names.